# How to make all the tooltips visible when a button is hovered for this example?

Tags: html, css, hover, visibility

I came across this pen which is a really cool floating share button. Here's the link:

http://codepen.io/koenigsegg1/pen/pjeJvb

**HTML**

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,200,300,400,500);
 body {
  background: #00BCD4;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Roboto;
  color: #fff;
}
h1 {
  font: 200 60px Roboto;
  text-align: center;
}
p.credits {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.credits img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
}
.container {
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 1em;
  right: 0px;
}
.buttons {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 11px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0px 4px 12px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
.buttons:active,
.buttons:focus,
.buttons:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .28);
}
.buttons:not(:last-child) {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
  transform: translateY(50px);
}
.container:hover .buttons:not(:last-child) {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  margin: 15px auto 0;
}
/* Unessential styling for sliding up buttons at differnt speeds */

.buttons:nth-last-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 25ms;
  transition-delay: 25ms; background-image: url('http://cbwconline.com/IMG/Share.svg'); background-size: contain; } .buttons:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(2) { -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms; transition-delay: 20ms; background-image: url('http://cbwconline.com/IMG/Facebook-Flat.png');
  background-size: contain; } .buttons:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(3) { -webkit-transition-delay: 75ms; transition-delay: 40ms; background-image: url('http://cbwconline.com/IMG/Twitter-Flat.png'); background-size: contain; } .buttons:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(4)
  {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms; transition-delay: 60ms; background-image: url('http://cbwconline.com/IMG/Google%20Plus.svg'); background-size: contain; } /* Show tooltip content on hover *
    [tooltip]: before {
      bottom: 25%;
      font-family: arial;
      font-weight: 600;
      border-radius: 2px;
      background: #585858;
      color: #fff;
      content: attr(tooltip);
      font-size: 12px;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      padding: 5px 7px;
      margin-right: 12px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    [tooltip]:hover:before,
    [tooltip]:hover:after {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Simple Share FAB</h1>
  <p class="credits">
    <a href="http://codepen.io/koenigsegg1" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/343394/profile/profile-80_3.jpg" />
    </a>
    <br />Pen by Kyle Lavery (@koenigsegg1)</p>
  <nav class="container">
    <a href="#" class="buttons" tooltip="Google+"></a>
    <a href="#" class="buttons" tooltip="Twitter"></a>
    <a href="#" class="buttons" tooltip="Facebook"></a>
    <a class="buttons" tooltip="Share" href="#"></a>
  </nav>
</body>
```

In the demo, you can see that if you hover on the share button, the other buttons pop up, and each button has a different tooltip.

Now, what I want to do is make all those tooltips visible as soon as the share button is hovered, instead of displaying them when that particular button is hovered. Is it possible to do using pure css? I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply a matter of toggling the visibility value of the CSS elements for `[tooltip]` attribute.

Also, remove the `[tooltip]:hover:before` and `[tooltip]:hover:after` properties.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,200,300,400,500);
 body {
  background: #00BCD4;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Roboto;
  color: #fff;
}
h1 {
  font: 200 60px Roboto;
  text-align: center;
}
p.credits {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.credits img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
}
.container {
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 1em;
  right: 0px;
}
.buttons {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 11px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0px 4px 12px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
.buttons:active,
.buttons:focus,
.buttons:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .28);
}
.buttons:not(:last-child) {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
  transform: translateY(50px);
}
.container:hover .buttons:not(:last-child) {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  margin: 15px auto 0;
}
/* Unessential styling for sliding up buttons at differnt speeds */

.buttons:nth-last-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 25ms;
  transition-delay: 25ms;
  background-image: url('http://cbwconline.com/IMG/Share.svg');
  background-size: contain;
}
.buttons:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms;
  transition-delay: 20ms;
  background-image: url('http://cbwconline.com/IMG/Facebook-Flat.png');
  background-size: contain;
}
.buttons:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 75ms;
  transition-delay: 40ms;
  background-image: url('http://cbwconline.com/IMG/Twitter-Flat.png');
  background-size: contain;
}
.buttons:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
  transition-delay: 60ms;
  background-image: url('http://cbwconline.com/IMG/Google%20Plus.svg');
  background-size: contain;
}
/* Show tooltip content on hover */

[tooltip]:before {
  bottom: 25%;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #585858;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(tooltip);
  font-size: 12px;
  /*
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  */
  padding: 5px 7px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Simple Share FAB</h1>
  <p class="credits">
    <a href="http://codepen.io/koenigsegg1" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/343394/profile/profile-80_3.jpg" />
    </a>
    <br />Pen by Kyle Lavery (@koenigsegg1)</p>
  <nav class="container">
    <a href="#" class="buttons" tooltip="Google+"></a>
    <a href="#" class="buttons" tooltip="Twitter"></a>
    <a href="#" class="buttons" tooltip="Facebook"></a>
    <a class="buttons" tooltip="Share" href="#"></a>
  </nav>
</body>
```